# Shortest code to generate 2D coordinates

Tags: code-golf, sequence

I'm looking for the shortest code to generate the following sequences:

```
Sequence A
i | y x
0 | 0 0
1 | 0 1
2 | 1 0
3 | 1 1
```

The best I have is `x = i % 2, y = i / 2`, there is probably no beating that. Those are coordinates of corners of a box in 2D, but they are not in a good order for drawing. To draw a box as line loop, one needs those coordinates:

```
Sequence B
i | y x
0 | 0 0
1 | 0 1
2 | 1 1
3 | 1 0
```

So far, I have `x = (i ^ i / 2) % 2, y = i / 2`. There is likely space for improvement there. Finally, how to generate directions towards the box edges (where the order does not matter, but `i` still must be 0 to 3):

```
Sequence C
i |  y  x
? |  0 -1
? |  0  1
? | -1  0
? |  1  0
```

So far I have rather ugly `x = (1 | -(i % 2)) * (i / 2), y = (1 | -(i % 2)) * (1 - i / 2)`.

Shortest code in any programming language wins (I actually plan to use these). The best solution will be used in a **closed-source** project, **no attribution** can be paid other than source code comment, so post only if you're ok with it. Submit solutions to any of the above sequences. Don't bother writing code that generates all of them, think of it like competition with three categories (and tree possible winners).

Comment: @ProgramFOX alright, I have changed rules and explicitly mentioned licensing. Fair enough?

Comment: Are people seriously getting offended by the closed source thing? What if I work in a company and want to use the knowledge from code golf in a commercial project? Not all software is open-source linux stuff. I imagine I'd be having a hard time convincing my boss to add attribution / license to the distribution of the final product. I thought the purpose of these sites is to provide knowledge. What good is it, if it can't be used by companies? Alternately I could just ignore the licensing and then use the answers anyway - who will ever know, right? I though I was being fair.

Comment: Why do you think people are offended? Because you get downvotes? People also downvote challenges they don't like, it's not because of the closed source.

Comment: Well I was just making sure, I'm new to this site.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need golfed production code? In a similar vein: it's only four pairs of numbers; why can't you store them in an array and look them up?

Comment: @m.buettner Simple answer: I don't, it is absolutely worthless to me. I could easily use an array and be done with it. But if I see a solution I like, I want to be able to use it. If I'm not able to use it, what good is it? Better if I don't see it at all, maybe I can figure it out by myself.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but I'm certainly not going to do your job for you.

Comment: @KyleKanos but why not? I've written online programming tutorials absolutely for free. I have never asked anyone to not use the code or to mention me in anything they write in the future. What about programming textbook authors? Imagine they would enforce license on everything you learn. We all do it for free and it is absolutely fine. Why is it a problem here? My point was to ask for solutions so others may see / use them as well.

Comment: Tutorials & textbooks have a solution already in mind in order to *teach* future programmers. You do not have such a solution already and are not actually teaching anyone anything. Instead, you are hoping to take other people's solutions to your own problems and get paid for someone else's work. Good luck.

Comment: @KyleKanos I have provided two solutions already, one using table and one using `x = (1 | -(i % 2)) * (i / 2), y = (1 | -(i % 2)) * (1 - i / 2)`. Am I supposed to come up with the best answer myself? Wouldn't that take the challenge of the code golf out, though? Have you been recently sacked? Why all that bitterness about me getting paid? Aren't you paid? And as I already said, the solution to this problem is worthless. I already have good enough solutions for my implementation. It is code golf. It is fun. I'm just being honest with how would I use a better answer, that's all.

Comment: If your job requires a better solution then what you've given, then you must certainly should give the best solution. Doing your work isn't much of a challenge. I have not been sacked, but I am also not a professional programmer (a physicist, if you want to know). I am not bitter about your job, just think it's wrong to ask people to do your work for you knowing *they* won't be credited for their work.

Comment: @KyleKanos but saying that up front is the fairness of it. Textbooks or free tutorials are written and the people who write them know they will not be credited, ever, only in extremely rare exceptional cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short sequence C (20 characters):

```
x=1==i^-!i,y=i%3-!!i
```

This generates a permutation of the original sequence (as I said, the order does not matter):

```
x -1  1  0  0
y  0  0  1 -1
```

Short sequence B (14 characters):

```
x=i>>~-i,y=i/2
```

So how about that? I'd say it is not possible to do better than that. Anyone to prove me wrong?

And yes, this answer is free. Use it as you want, sell it, no attribution needed.

**EDIT**:

Shorter sequence C (17 characters):

```
x=~-i%2,y=~-~-i%2
```

This generates a permutation of the original sequence (as I said, the order does not matter):

```
x -1  0  1  0
y  0 -1  0  1
```

Some other interesting solutions to short sequences:

```
was solving for {0, 0, 1, 1} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: '1 < i': score 3
solution: 'i > 1': score 3
solution: 'i / 2': score 3

was solving for {0, 1, 0, 1} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: '1 & i': score 3
solution: 'i & 1': score 3
solution: 'i % 2': score 3

was solving for {0, 1, 1, 0} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: 'i >> ~-i': score 6
solution: '!!(i % 3)': score 7
solution: 'i >> ~(-i)': score 8

was solving for {-1, 1, 0, 0} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: '!~-i - !i': score 7
solution: '!~-i + -!i': score 8
solution: '!~-i | -!i': score 8

was solving for {1, -1, 0, 0} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: '!i - !~-i': score 7
solution: '!i - !(~-i)': score 9
solution: '-!(~-i) + !i': score 10

was solving for {1, 0, 0, -1} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: '-~(~i / 2)': score 8
solution: '-~(-i >> 1)': score 9
solution: '-(~-i >> 1)': score 9

was solving for {-1, 0, 0, 1} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: '~-i >> 1': score 6
solution: '~(~i / 2)': score 7
solution: '~-i >> !!i': score 8

was solving for {0, 1, -1, 0} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: '~(~i % 3)': score 7
solution: '~(~i % ~2)': score 8
solution: '~(~i % -3)': score 8

was solving for {0, -1, 1, 0} in 1D {4 x 1 x 1} domain
solution: '-~(~i % 3)': score 8
solution: '-~(~i % ~2)': score 9
solution: '-~(~i % -3)': score 9
```